# rst2pdf: Referencing automatically-numbered figures

Tags: python, restructuredtext, rst2pdf

I have directives in my rst document, which insert figures; and I use [`rst2pdf`](http://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/)'s `:counter:` directive to automatically number them.

```
.. figure:: Graphics\Manual_test_timeline.png
   :scale: 100%
   :align: center

   Figure :counter:`figure`. Manual Testing Timeline
```

The caption renders as *Figure 1.  Manual Testing Timeline*.

How can I reference those automatically numbered figures elsewhere in the document?   I need to be able to write

> See ??? for more details on the timeline.

Where ??? is a reference to the text in caption of the figure (including the number).

Is there a way to do this with either standard restructured text or a special [`rst2pdf`](http://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/) hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that automatically. There are, of course, ways to do that manually.

Comment: +1 and an accept for `rst2pdf`'s author.  Thank you for your contributions to the community

Answer (score 2):

If you can sacrifice the figure number, then this would work with a hyperlink:

```
.. _Manual Testing Timeline:

.. figure:: Graphics\Manual_test_timeline.png
   :scale: 100%
   :align: center

   Figure :counter:`figure`. Manual Testing Timeline

Here is some text referencing `Manual Testing Timeline`_
```

But if you can't sacrifice the figure number, I can't think of any solution.

The syntax `Text <#figure-1>` could be something to look into as well.

Comment: Thanks, sadly I do need to include Figure numbering.